# Why does Python list initialization method affect indexing?

Tags: python, list, cpython

I recently stumbled on some serious weirdness with python lists if you try to use them like arrays (not by appending):

make a list by duplication:

```
myLists = 5 * [3 * [0]]
print(myLists)
```

[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

run this...you get:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(3):
        myLists[i][j] = i + j
print(myLists)
```

[[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]

**why only the last row copied everywhere?**

now, create the list contiguously with list comprehension:

```
myLists = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(5)]
print(myLists)
```

here it is (it's the same structure):

[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

run the same loops...now you get:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(3):
        myLists[i][j] = i + j
print(myLists)
```

[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]]

**now it's correct...**

I'm guessing some strange linked-list-related pointer details under the CPython hood cause this, but I don't know what they are...

Can anyone help?

Comment: You multiplied the same list 3 times. You didn't create 3 copies.

Comment: `myLists` is a `list` of 5 identical `list` object.  Check the `id(myLists[i])` and you'll understand.

Comment: Note, CPython `list` objects are not implemented as linked-lists. They are implemented as array lists.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!